# How to test screen.width condition using karma and jasmine

Tags: angularjs, testing, jasmine, width, screen

For a while now I'm struggling with testing a simple if statement in my controller.

```
if (screen.width <= 768) {
                $location.hash('map');
                $anchorScroll();
            }
```

I found a way to spawn the browser with a different size but it didn't work the `screen.width` always stays the same. Is there a way to cover that part of the code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, There is a way.

You will have to replace `screen.width` with `$window.screen.width` and you can mock `window` object in jasmine.

Then, You can mock window using below code:

```
var window = {
  screen : {
      width : 500
     }
};
```

now in your spec file : in beforeEach block

```
$controller('controllerName', {$window : window});
```

Answer (score 8):

I'm using Angular 8. I used karma-viewport plugin to mock the screen size and it works well to me.

The package is available at https://www.npmjs.com/package/karma-viewport.

In the karma.conf.js I have to add viewport to frameworks and require the package in plugins.

My karma.conf.js:

```
frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular', 'viewport'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-junit-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
      require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma'),
      require('karma-viewport')
    ],
```

In my .spec.ts file I added the viewport var declaration:

```
declare const viewport: any;
```

Changed the size in the "it" function, called my method that changes a variable according to the screen size and after checked the result. In my case the property width of the component should be 240 when the screen size is less than 700px:

```
it('test xyz', () => {
    viewport.set(320, 240);
    component.changeHeightByScreenSize();
    expect(component.width).toEqual(240);
  });
```

Comment: Yesss!! That worked for me, just needed to install karma-viewport, configure the karma.conf.js and it worked. Thank you!!!

Comment: Instead of declaring `viewport` variable, add `karma-viewport` value to `types` array (it's located inside `compilerOptions` object) in `tsconfig.spec.json` file - from now it'll be enabled globally and you can avoid repeating this declaration in your `*.spec.ts` files

Answer (score 2):

*Angular 4* with *TypeScript* here:

```
(<any>window).screen = { width: 300 };
```

Casting `window` as `any` should work during a unit test.